# Chatter feeds not appearing correctly on Vf page

Tags: visualforce, chatter

I am showing a chatter feeds in my VF page by using the following

```
<chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!theCase.id}"/>
```

The feeds dont seem to be displaying correctly.  I cant see the feeds on the record level on the VF page but the updates are visible on the home screen.

On VF page
[image]

On Home  screen
[image]

Comment: try using case.id as entity id .Is it site visualforce page ? try changing object as well and see if this happens only for case or all object .try changing the org and see if its org specific ?

Comment: Strangely.. It started to work after sometime.. :)

Comment: @MohithShrivastava ,Prady,    I have a same issue. please help!